# Is it mandatory to pass props to react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional react component. It does not use any props, it just return elements. Have I pass props to it anyway? Are there any agreements about that? Will be code below valid React code?

```
const HelloComponent = () => (
    <div>Hi!</div>
);
```

Comment: The above code will be valid. You do not need to add the `props` parameter in the function definition unless you want to use it

Answer (score 5):

No you don't. `props` are explicitly passed to each component. If you don't use any `property` from it, just don't declare it. Exactly like in your example. Consider the following

```
const App = () => <Child />

const Child = props => {
    console.log(props) // { }
    return <div>hey</div>
}
```

In this case `props` is just an empty `Object` and there is no need to declare the `argument`. If you don't need to read from it, don't even mention it

```
const Child = () => <div>hey</div>
```

Comment: They are just like javascript functions so if you need an argument in a function then you pass them else leave them empty.

Comment: Will be there some problems if I will pass className to my component?

Answer (score 3):

It is completly valid, there is no need for props. Its the same as with any other function, if it doesnt have arguments, dont give it any. :-)

Answer (score 3):

As functional react components are just javascript functions the same rules apply to them as they do for any function. You can safely omit unused arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1. The code you've mentioned is valid.

Pattern A

```
// span on single line and returns by default..
const Test = () => <div>Hello</div>
```

Pattern B

```
// span on multiple lines, still returns by default a single node
const Test = () => 
 <div>
  Hello
 </div>
```

Pattern C

```
//span on multiple lines, but grouped by a paranthesis
const Test = () => (
 <div>
  Hello
 </div>
)
```

WRONG..

```
//tryin to group with braces..
const Test = () => {
 <div>
  Hello
 </div>
}
```

Pattern D:

```
// group by braces, so you have to return explicitly
const Test = () => {
 const greeting = 'hello'

 return (
  <div>
   {greeting}
  </div>
 )
}
```

Note: 
it's not possible to return multiple nodes in react. all the nodes must have a single parent as it's root. why {} braces fails is because, it is used to group multiple nodes or code fragments.

//container
//destructure props from other end

```
 render() {
    const obj = {
     name: 'john',
     isAdmin: true,
    }

  return <Child {..{ obj }} {...this.props} />
 }
```

// child: destructure from here

```
const Child = ({ obj, ...props }) => {
 const { value1-in-props, value2-in-props } = props
}
```

//container
//destructure whilst sending

```
 render() {
    const obj = {
     name: 'john',
     isAdmin: true,
    }

  return <Child {..obj} {...this.props} />
 }
```

// child: destructure

```
const Child = ({ name, isAdmin, ...props }) => {}
```